# Why does the first radio button tilt towards the left more than the following sibling radio buttons?

Tags: html, radio-button

I have added no styling whatsoever and this is what I see.

[image]

My code contains only html and is as found below:-

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <input type="radio" name="q3" value="elon" />Elon Musk<br />
          <input type="radio" name="q3" value="nikola" />Nikola Tesla<br />
          <input type="radio" name="q3" value="bill" />Bill Gates<br />
          <input type="radio" name="q3" value="jeffrey" />Jeffrey Archer<br />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to the whitespace in your code. Just remove it:

```html
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="elon" />Elon Musk<br />
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="nikola" />Nikola Tesla<br />
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="bill" />Bill Gates<br />
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="jeffrey" />Jeffrey Archer<br />
```